How to fix memory errors merging large dask dataframes?
I am trying to read 23 CSV files into dask dataframes, merge them together using dask, and ouptut to parquet. However, it's failing due to memory issues.
I used to use pandas to join these together but due to increased size of data pandas no longer completes and the kernel kills the process after joining only a couple together. I confirmed it's a memory issue by running dmesg and seeing the process was killed with message: Out of memory: Killed process 25693 (ld-linux-x86-64) total-vm:125749916kB.
I'd appreciate any guidance to help me solve this problem.
Some things I've tried:

Indexing to do a sorted join on date column

Currently implementing this but still running into issues


Set index on date column and partition by that column using df.repartition(freq='7d')

I played around with the frequency which adjusts the number of partitions and got more of the computation done, but it still results in memory usage being high and then eventually the workers die off usually with the error worker died unexpectedly and don't get recreated


Joining each of the 22 CSV files to the base dataframe by themselves

This works, confirming it is not an issue with any individual join but rather doing them all together at once


Try making only base dataframe a dask dataframe and read in the others as pandas dataframes

Fails with serialization error complaining about graph size being 49GiB


Compressing the shuffle partitions to reduce file sizes

Still does not fix



Here's my code structure:
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask

cluster = LocalCluster()
dask_client = cluster.get_client()
dask.config.set({'distributed.worker.shuffle-compression': 'snappy'})

base_df = dd.read_csv(
    my_path,
    keep_default_na=False,
    parse_dates=[6],
    date_format="%Y-%m-%d",
    blocksize='100MB'
)
base_df = base_df.set_index("date")

file_list = ['file_1','file_2','file_3',...,'file_22']
for file_name in file_list:
    metrics_file = "/my/path/" + file_name + '.csv'
    metric_df = dd.read_csv(
        metrics_file,
        keep_default_na=False,
        parse_dates=[6],
        date_format="%Y-%m-%d"
    )
    metric_df = metric_df.set_index("date")

    base_df = dd.merge(base_df, metric_df, on=['date','att_1','att_2','att_3','att_4','att_5','att_6','att_7'], how="left")
dd.to_parquet(
    base_df,
    's3://my-bucket/path',
    engine='pyarrow',
    compression='snappy',
    overwrite=True,
    write_index=False,
    storage_options={'key': aws.access_key, 'secret': aws.secret_key}
)

Here are some characteristics of the files I'm working with:
Size    Rows    Partitions
3.4G    59403457    35
4.1G    31400625    68
25k 521 1
776M    9040235 12
3.1G    16744261    50
1.7G    18134657    26
7.0G    35947667    115
848M    6859497 13
681M    6859497 11
6.3G    34482809    104
937M    4065205 15
90M 1260421 1
2.7M    30830   1
7.1M    121765  1
611M    5690153 10
627M    5690153 10
5.9G    22052565    98
2.7G    15585577    44
3.4G    15585577    56
499M    3691933 8
720M    3683677 11
3.7G    42168165    60
3.3G    31619653    54

This is the cardinality of the columns I'm using to join:
date: 1460+
att_1: 56
att_2: 3
att_3: 5
att_4: 5
att_5: 3
att_6: 3
att_7: 5

Here is the error message that occurs during the to_parquet call (since dask implements lazy evaluation):
First many shuffle warnings: distributed.shuffle._scheduler_plugin - WARNING - Shuffle 99748e0284e4fcb627e68b744953791a
Then repeated garbage collection: distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 15% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
Then issues with memory: WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS;
Then more memory issues: WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:36199 (pid=20601) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
Then WARNING - Restarting worker
Finally Attempted to run task on 4 different workers, but all those workers died while running it.
I'm running on a local host. Here are my specs:
OS: Linux
Memory: 124G
Disk: 493G
CPU: 16 cores (32 threads)
Architecture: x86_64

Below is what my dask status shows when it starts its garbage collection phase. It  looks like only one task is processing. I'm unable to troubleshoot the task graph because dask says it's too large to display.
dask dashboard during execution


Hi, first, there is something weird in your code, it looks like you don't reuse the merged_df variable across loops. Then, are all your dataframe the same structure? Could you read them all and then try to set an index?

Thanks for catching that. I replaced merged_df with base_df so it's reused in the loop which is how I actually use it but mistyped when creating this post. No, all my dataframes are not the same structure. They all have the 8 columns I join on but then also include a varying amount of numeric columns. I try to set an index on the date column in each dataframe since that join column has the highest cardinality. I didn't set any others as indexes since dask doesn't support more than one.  I also tried partitioning the dataframes on the date column but that didn't work either.
